# How to bind PivotItems dynamically to html pages

Tags: javascript, winjs, windows-phone-8.1

So I'm trying to create an app with a [WinJS.UI.Pivot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn624879.aspx) control. The documentation is very simple, and the samples I've seen are "for dummies".

I know I can add my html under the [PivotItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn624871.aspx) control and I've also seen a way of binding the control of a child element vie the `data-win-control` to a ControlConstructor that defines a page in a javascript file, as seen here:

```
    (function () {
        "use strict";

        var ControlConstructor = WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/pages/hub/section1Page.html", {
            // This function is called after the page control contents 
            // have been loaded, controls have been activated, and 
            // the resulting elements have been parented to the DOM. 
            ready: function (element, options) {
                options = options || {};
            },
        });

        // The following lines expose this control constructor as a global. 
        // This lets you use the control as a declarative control inside the 
        // data-win-control attribute. 

        WinJS.Namespace.define("HubApps_SectionControls", {
            Section1Control: ControlConstructor
        });
    })();
```

Is there a way to do this dynamically (programmatically)?

Comment: Are you talking about programmatically adding a PivotItem to a WinJS.UI.Pivot control?

Comment: yes, that's what I was asking, but I already solved my original issue... I'll be glad to see it thoug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a sneak peak of some code from the upcoming new release of codeShow which will work on the phone.

```
//render pivot items for sections
var sectionsPivot = element.querySelector(".sections").winControl;
options.demo.data.sections.forEach(function (section) {
    var pivotItem = new WinJS.UI.PivotItem(document.createElement("div"), { isHeaderStatic: true, header: section.title });
    pivotItem.element.classList.add(options.demo.data.name);
    var pivotItemContent = pivotItem.element.querySelector(".win-pivot-item-content");
    WinJS.UI.Pages.render(Ocho.Utilities.format("/demos/{0}/{1}/{1}.html", options.demo.data.name, section.name), pivotItemContent)
        .then(function (page) {
            //remove the section header since the demo page has one already
            var header = page.element.querySelector("header.page-header");
            if (header) header.style.display = "none";
        });
    sectionsPivot.items.push(pivotItem);
});
```

The WinJS.UI.PivotItem is being created in a new (in-memory) div element, some content is being added to the pivot item's content child, and then I'm pushing it into the pivot control's items collection.
Hope that helps.

Comment: cool thanks, you just reminded me to go check the codeShow code

Comment: It's in great flux right now. What I checked in last night was pretty big, but still a little messy. I'll send an email out to contributors once I get it stable. We're going to do another big MVA show in late August, so I need to get it to a good place.

Comment: let me know if there's anything I can help with

Comment: This solution works great, but has interesting side effect. Because `sectionsPivot.items` is of type `WinJS.Binding.List`, every time you push `pivotItem` into this list, it will trigger "item added" event and this will force parent `Pivot` to play animation of item "sliding into" parent `Pivot`. When adding 3+ items, this animation takes like 5 seconds and looks like a deck cards flipping.  The solution would be to create first and array of `pivotItems`, later wrap it in `WinJS.Bindling.List` and after assign this list to `sectionsPivot.items`. HTH